# Loop through elements and incrementally apply CSS rule for each one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a grid layout, with variable amounts of elements in each one. I would like to dynamically add inline `grid-column` CSS rules for each element that is present in a div by looping through each `<ul>` with a class of `.list`. So the output of the code in HTML needs to be:

```
<ul class="list" style="grid-column: 1;"></ul>
<ul class="list" style="grid-column: 2;"></ul>
<ul class="list" style="grid-column: 3;"></ul>
```

Below is the code sample:

```js
// iterate through each div named "list item"
$(".list-item").each(function() {
  // get the amount of each ul within the div
  var listAmount = $(".list-item > .sub-list").size();
  // I also tried:
  // var listAmount = $(".list-item > .sub-list").length;

  // for each one that is present within the div,
  for (var i = 0; i < listAmount.length; i++) {
    // apply the CSS "grid-column" of 1, 2, 3, 4 which is defined by i
    $(".sub-list").css("grid-column", i);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-item">
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="list__header"><a href="#">Main Item</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="list">
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="list__header"><a href="#">Main Item</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="list-item">
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="list__header"><a href="#">Main Item</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="list">
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="list">
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="list">
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="list__header"><a href="#">Main Item</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="list-item">
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="list__header"><a href="#">Main Item</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="list">
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="list">
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="list">
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="list__header"><a href="#">Main Item</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Unfortunately the inline styles aren't applying as expected.

My JS snippet is commented with my train of thought. I don't understand why this doesn't work, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just click the Tidy button in the snippet editor.

Comment: Do you need to restart the `grid-column` count for each `list-item` or keep a global counter?

Comment: @xavvvier yes the count should be reset for each instance of `list-item`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are looping through you are not actually going through sub lists. You have to loop though each sub-list within each list and add css to it.

Here is a working example

```js
var listItems = jQuery('.list-item');
listItems.each(function(index, value) {
  $(value).find('.list').each(function(i, list) {
    //index will start from 0, adding 1 to make grid-column 
    // start from 1
    //adding empty string to convert it into a string
    var columnSize = i + 1 + "";
    $(list).css('grid-column', columnSize);
  });
});
```

```css
.list-item {
  display: grid;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="list-item">
    <ul class="list">
      <li class="list__header"><a href="#">Main Item</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="list">
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="list">
      <li class="list__header"><a href="#">Main Item</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="list-item">
    <ul class="list">
      <li class="list__header"><a href="#">Main Item</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="list">
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="list">
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="list">
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="list">
      <li class="list__header"><a href="#">Main Item</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="list-item">
    <ul class="list">
      <li class="list__header"><a href="#">Main Item</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="list">
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="list">
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="list">
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="list">
      <li class="list__header"><a href="#">Main Item</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is a plunker of the above snippet https://plnkr.co/edit/CVthyQ8mcYUFKpomfFar?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

1. Iterate over each `.list-item`
2. Search `ul.list` using each `.list-item` element as filter
3. apply the `grid-column` style to each `ul.list`. Note how the `each` function arguments allows you reference the current index and object (`i` and `obj`)

```js
// iterate through each div named "list item"
$(".list-item").each(function(a, listItem) {
  var list = $(listItem);
  var sublist = $("ul.list", list);
  sublist.each(function(i, obj){
    $(obj).css("grid-column", i+1);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-item">
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="list__header"><a href="#">Main Item</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="list">
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="list__header"><a href="#">Main Item</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="list-item">
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="list__header"><a href="#">Main Item</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="list">
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="list">
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="list">
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="list__header"><a href="#">Main Item</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="list-item">
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="list__header"><a href="#">Main Item</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="list">
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="list">
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="list">
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="list__header"><a href="#">Main Item</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are applying the style to all sub-lists every iteration. I think you need to change this:

```
var subLists = $(".list-item > .sub-list");

for (var i = 0; i < subLists.length; i++) {
  subLists.get(i).css("grid-column", i);
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's related to `get()` that has more to do with an Ajax call https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/