# Apply an inline style if each() returns more than 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I asked a question yesterday about looping through elements and applying inline styles, which can be seen here: [Loop through elements and incrementally apply CSS rule for each one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48668611/loop-through-elements-and-incrementally-apply-css-rule-for-each-one)

To build off of it, I want to apply another inline style to the current div only if the condition of having more than 4 `<ul>`s is true.

This is what my code is currently:

```js
$(function() {
  var listItems = $(".list-item");
  listItems.each(function(index, value) {
    $(value).find(".list").each(function(i, list) {
      var columnSize = i + 1 + "";
      if (columnSize > 4) {
        console.log("it's more")
        $(".list-item", this).css("left", "-125px");
      }
      $(list).css("grid-column", columnSize);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.list-item {
  display: grid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-item">
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="list__header"><a href="#">Main Item</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="list">
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="list__header"><a href="#">Main Item</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="list-item">
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="list__header"><a href="#">Main Item</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="list">
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="list">
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="list">
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="list__header"><a href="#">Main Item</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="list-item">
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="list__header"><a href="#">Main Item</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="list">
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="list">
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="list">
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="list__header"><a href="#">Main Item</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

We can see the console.log is working (so the logic is working) but the inline CSS is not being applied. Why would that be?

Comment: So I tried using  `$(this)` but that targets the `<ul>` and not `.list-item`

Comment: `.list-item` is not a descendent of `this` so `$(".list-item", this)` won't find anything - try : `$(this).closest(".list-item").css("color", "red");` to find the parent list-item.   Also `left` won't have any effect unless your items are positioned - you could try `margin-left`

Comment: @freedomn-m they are positioned absolute in source, but I just did not include in example

Comment: @freedomn-m your suggestion worked, if you want to formally answer I can accept

Comment: Glad you got it sorted - I only added the 'red' while testing as `left` did nothing in the provided code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
$(".list-item", this)
```

looks for nodes with class `list-item` that are descendants of `this`.  As `.list-item` is an ancestor, you need to change it to:

```
$(this).closest(".list-item")
```

to select the specific container for the `ul` (this).